# QuickCheck and State monad

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, state-monad

I have written a Haskell module that contains functions that operate on some state. Let's say that the code looks like this (the actual functions may return an actual result instead of `()`, but this is irrelevant to the question):

```
data StateContext = StateContext {
  -- some records
}

handleEventA :: EventA -> State StateContext ()
handleEventB :: EventB -> State StateContext ()
handleEventC :: EventC -> State StateContext ()
```

As you can imagine the behavior of each function depends on the current state. For example `handleEventA >> handleEventB` will not produce the same result as `handleEventB >> handleEventA`. So I have several HUnit tests that verify the behavior of each function at several states.

But now I would like to write more tests, that exercise all functions at all possible states (the number of states is finite). Writing them with HUnit would be quite labor-itensive, so I thought that using QuickCheck might be helpful in that case (I have only used it before for trivial functions).

But I cannot see which properties should I test, or what kind of data should the test generate. I suspect that the test should generate random sequence of events (e.g. `handleEventB >> handleEventC >> handleEventA` etc), but I cannot see what properties should be satisfied.

Comment: The properties you want to test are likely specific to your program. Perhaps you can extrapolate from your HUnit tests to find some more general properties that should hold.

Comment: Yeah, it'd help to know more about your domain, and to have a running program, but some suggestions:  is there some sequence of events that must occur to reach some state? For example, on a web site, there might be a login and password before a  "view the sensitive info" page. Or, in a vending machine, all events must end in one of: returned change, or vended drink.  Or, if you're modelling an office process, the event "cut a check" must the proceeded by a "issued purchase order", ..., "received invoice", .....

Comment: Also, since the number of states is finite, have a look at [Smallcheck](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/smallcheck/smallcheck.pdf).